# Fiscal Period Name from varchar column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I fairly new to SQL and learning so much from this forum. Thank All!

Have another one for which I seek expert advice.

I have a column which basically is fiscal period. However, its not a date column, but instead of type `varchar`.

Intention is to manipulate the column value to get the name of the fiscal month out of it.

So in the example below, I have column `Fiscal_Period` available and I need column `FiscalMonth`.

```
Fiscal_Period   FiscalMonth
----------------------------
2018001             Jan
2018002             Feb
2018003             Mar
2018004             Apr
2018005             May
2018006             Jun
2018007             Jul
2018008             Aug
2018009             Sep
2018010             Oct
2018011             Nov
2018012             Dec
```

Is there a straightforward way of achieving this then the way I am then trying?

My current hack approach is:

1. Convert `Fiscal_Period` column filed into `YYYY-DD-MM` format by using substring and concat function
2. Use `Datetime` to convert into date and then extract month out of it
3. Use `Month` and `Datename` function

My query:

```
SELECT 
    DATENAME(MONTH, (CONVERT(DATETIME, (CONCAT(SUBSTRING(FISCAL_PERIOD, 1, 4), '-', SUBSTRING(FISCAL_PERIOD, 6, LEN(FISCAL_PERIOD)), '-', '11'))))) AS PeriodName 
FROM
    table 1
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is slightly shorter

```
datename(month, stuff(FISCAL_PERIOD, 5, 1, '-') + '-01')
```

if you only wanted the abbreviated month name then apply LEFT ( ) on the above expression

Comment: Great Thanks Squirrel!

Answer (score 2):

As you only need a month name neither the year or day need to vary, hence you can use constants for those. In T-SQL a literal that equates to YYYYMMDD is safe to use as a date, so:

```
select datename(month,'2018' + right(fiscal_period,2) + '01')
```

Comment: You are right but i am looking for year as well to generate something like '2018_Jul'. However to get the month name your method is spot on.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically the answers already given, just figured id finish typing it. It relies on filling in a problem with the date format as given, but otherwise it works the same.

```
;with src (dt) as
(

select convert(date, '20180101', 120) union all
select '20180201' union all
select '20180301' union all
select '20180401' union all
select '20180501' union all
select '20180601' union all
select '20180701' union all
select '20180801' union all
select '20180901' union all
select '20181001' union all
select '20181101' union all
select '20181201'
)
select 
    Dt,
    left(datename(month, dt), 3)
from src
```